# UIScrollView keep buttons in fixed position

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I am using UIScrollView for pinch zooming the image the code I am using is like this

```
CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; //Full Screen
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scroll.delegate = self;

scroll.contentSize = _imageView.frame.size;

[scroll addSubview:_imageView];
scroll.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scroll.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
[scroll setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];
self.view = scroll;


[scroll addSubview:_screenShotButton];
[scroll addSubview:_resolutionButton];

-(void)aligementTheControlBasedOnOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
  bool ipad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
   if (ipad) {

      if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
      {
           _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(142, 114, 740, 555);

           if ([self.resoultion isEqualToString:@"Default"]) {
                _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(142, 114, 740, 555);
           }
           else if([self.resoultion isEqualToString:@"4:3"])
                _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(142, 114, 740, 555);
           else if([self.resoultion isEqualToString:@"16:9"])
                _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(142, 114, 740, 416);

           self.screenShotButton.frame = CGRectMake(794, 667, 55, 55);

           self.resolutionButton.frame = CGRectMake(857, 667, 55, 55);
      }
      else
      {
           _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(64, 238, 640, 480);

           if ([self.resoultion isEqualToString:@"Default"]) {
                _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(64, 238, 640, 480);
           }
           else if([self.resoultion isEqualToString:@"4:3"])
                _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(64, 238, 640, 480);
           else if([self.resoultion isEqualToString:@"16:9"])
                _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(64, 238, 640, 360);

           self.screenShotButton.frame = CGRectMake(578, 749, 55, 55);

           self.resolutionButton.frame = CGRectMake(649, 749, 55, 55);
      }
 }
}
```

Based on the resolution user has chosen I am positioning the buttons.

Everything is working fine for me. The problem I am facing is _screenShotButton and _resolutionButton are also moving when I zoom the image. Instead I want to keep the buttons static in the bottom right side of the screen.

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not add your buttons to the scroll view, but to its parent instead.

This part is wrong:

```
[scroll addSubview:_screenShotButton];
[scroll addSubview:_resolutionButton];
```

Assuming *scroll* has a `superview` (which in your original question it does not), do this instead:

```
[scroll.superview addSubview:_screenShotButton];
[scroll.superview addSubview:_resolutionButton];
```

Alternatively, you can pick the order of scroll vs. screenShotButton by replacing `-addSubView:` by one of the `-insertSubview::` methods.

Comment: I also noticed you replaced the `self.view` by your `scroll`. Consider *adding* scroll to `self.view` as a subview of `self.view`, so that you will have a superview to add the buttons to.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it making moving sub view from `UIScrollView` to super view of scrollview like:

Place/set your button over scroll view (not inside scroll view) as shown here in this snapshot. And also set button constraints (position) with respect to super view of your scrollview.

[image]

Here is ref. snapshot of hierarchy of position of each view over each-other.

[image]